# How to Access WordPress Posts as Subdomains Instead of Subdirectories?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, wildcard, http-status-code-403, permalinks

I'm trying to configure my WordPress website to allow access to posts in subdomains format instead of the default permalinks structure. For example:

The current permalink structure for the website is:
domainname.com/%postname%

And the required/desired outcome would be:
%postname%.domainname.com/

I've already set up a wildcard subdomain on my hosting provider and tried using the "Post as Subdomain" plugin (https://pe.wordpress.org/plugins/post-as-subdomain-free/). While the plugin successfully converts the post URLs to the desired format, attempting to access them results in a "403 Forbidden" error:

> 403
> Forbidden
> Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I've contacted my hosting provider's technical support, and they confirmed that the wildcard subdomain setup is functioning correctly. However, I'm still unable to access the posts via subdomains.

The reason I'm pursuing this setup is that I'm using the MyListing theme (https://themeforest.net/item/mylisting-directory-listing-wordpress-theme/20593226), and I want to utilize subdomains to access all the listing URLs for better organization and SEO.

Required format:

my-blog-post.domain.com

instead of

domain.com/my-blog-post

Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly configure WordPress to allow access to posts using subdomains? Any alternative methods or configurations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to have the subdomains created from your provider tools and install wp and db to each one of them. You can't use permalinks and subdomains interchangeably.

Comment: I have 1000+ posts, and I want to access it in subdomains pattern before domain dynamically. 

example: %postname%.domain.com